# PHP uploading into the database ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anything wrong with this query?

I can't seems to insert the data into my database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES('', '$name', 'videos/$random_name.$type')");
```

Not sure if this helps but this is the one that connects to my database.

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($db, 'video_system');
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Is it because you're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`? I don't use either so I'm not sure.

Comment: he may trying to insert direct from folder to database ... just like file copy past...

Answer (score 3):

you are connect with the mysqli driver but make your query with mysql_

first of all use mysqli or mysql... then don't forget to escape your strings!

escape with

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($your_mysqli_connection, $string);
```

and check your connection first like

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect(....);

    if(false === $connection ){
        //connection failed.. do something!
        exit;
    }
```

also your selection

```
    $selection = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'your_db_name');

    if(false === $selection ){
        //selection failed.. do something!
        exit;
    }
```

run your query like this

```
mysql_query('mysqlscripts are cool', $connection);
```

Comment: You commented the wrong post...

Comment: sorry about that... corrected

Comment: Thank you so much! But however when I decided to use mysqli for all. 

It has a different problem now. 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

I am sorry. I am still really new in the PHP world.

Comment: yes.... the second argument is your created connection (watch my last statement)

Answer (score 3):

It is because you're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`

Be sure to use one and stick to one (however `mysqli_*` is the preferred method).

Read up on [this link](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) to learn how to use `mysqli_*` properly.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! The link helped me a lot! I managed to solved it! How do I add rep? :D

Comment: Press the up arrow on the left of the answer and click the tick if it was the answer you were looking for :) @Moonlightcoder